# C: Function Running differently in Separate instances

Tags: c, string, caesar-cipher, cs50

I am following the iTunes University: Harvard CS50 lectures in order to learn the basics of programming.  I am currently trying to create a program for a text cypher.   Here is the code for the entire program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int cyphmain (void);
int decyphmain (void);
int maincalc (int k);
int dmaincalc (int k);
int uppercalc (int u, int k);
int lowercalc (int u, int k);
int duppercalc (int u, int k);
int dlowercalc (int u, int k);

int 
main(void)                                  //Main Function begins by asking the user if he would like to Cypher or Decypher his text
{
    char h;
    printf("Do You Want Cypher(c) or Decypher(d)?:");
    scanf("%c",&h);                      
    if (h==99)                              //Checks ascii of "c"(99) and runs the cypher main function
        cyphmain();
    else if (h==100)                        //Checks ascii of "d"(100) and runs the decypher main function
        decyphmain();                   
    else 
        return 0;
}

int cyphmain (void)                         //Cypher Main Function
{
    int k;
    printf("What is the Cypher Number:");   //Gets the rot number
    scanf("%d",&k);
        if (k>25)                           //Ensures that the User only choses a number from 1-25
        {   while (k>25)                    //Continues to ask user for a number until they input a value <=25
            {
                printf("Sorry Please Choose A Number from 1-25 only:");
                int l=GetInt();
                k=l;
            }
            maincalc(k);                    //as soon as a valid input is received maincalc function is run
        }    
        else                                //in this case a valid input has been  recieved and maincalc runs
            maincalc(k);   
     return 0;      
}

int decyphmain (void)                       //Decypher Main Function
{
    int k;
    printf("What is the Cypher Number:");   //Gets the rot number
    scanf("%d",&k);
        if (k>25)                           //Ensures that the User only choses a number from 1-25
        {   while (k>25)                    //Continues to ask user for a number until they input a value <=25
            {
                printf("Sorry Please Choose A Number from 1-25 only:");
                int l=GetInt();
                k=l;
            }
            dmaincalc(k);                   //as soon as a valid input is received maincalc funtion is run
        }    
        else                                //in this case a valid input has been recieved and maincalc runs
            dmaincalc(k);   
        return 0;
}

int maincalc(int k)                         //The Calculation Function for Cyphering
{
    char *s;
    printf("Please enter the phrase that you would like to code:");  
    scanf("%s",&s);
    int i=0;
    int n=strlen(s);

    while(i<n)
    {
        if(s[i]>=65&&s[i]<=90)              //For Uppercase letters
        {
            int u=s[i];
            int c=uppercalc(u,k);           //Hands off the character to a function to cypher Upper Case Letters
            printf("%c",c);
        }
        else if(s[i]>=97&&s[i]<=122)        //For Lowercase letters
        {
            int u=s[i];
            int c=lowercalc(u,k);           //Hands off the character to a function to cypher Lower Case Letters
            printf("%c",c);
        }
        else 
            printf("%c",s[i]);              //For non letters
        i++;
    }    
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}


int uppercalc(int u, int k)                 //Algorithm used to cypher Upper Case     letters
{
    if(u+k<=90)
    {
        int c=u+k;
        return (c);
    }
    else 
    {
        if (((u+k)/26)==3)
        {
            int c=((u+k)%26)+52;
            return (c);
        }
        else
        {  
            int c=((u+k)%26)+78;
            return (c);
        }
    }
}

int lowercalc(int u, int k)                 //Algorithms used to Cypher lower case     letters
{
    if(u+k<=122)
    {
        int c=u+k;
        return (c);
    }
    else
    {
        if (((u+k)/26)==4)
        {
            int c=((u+k)%26)+78;
            return (c);
        }
        else 
        {
            int c=((u+k)%26)+104;
            return (c);
        }
     }
}

int dmaincalc(int k)                         //The Calculation Function for Decyphering 
{
    char *s;
    printf("Please enter the phrase that you would like to decode:");  
    scanf("%s",&s);
    int i=0;
    int n=strlen(s);

    while(i<n)
    {
        if(s[i]>=65&&s[i]<=90)              //For Uppercase letters
        {
            int u=s[i];
            int c=duppercalc(u,k);
            printf("%c",c);
        }
        else if(s[i]>=97&&s[i]<=122)    //For Lowercase letters
        {
            int u=s[i];
            int c=dlowercalc(u,k);
            printf("%c",c);
        }
        else 
            printf("%c",s[i]);          //For non letters
        i++;
    }    
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int duppercalc(int u, int k)             //Algorithm to decypher Upper Case letters
{
    if(u-k>=65)
    {
        int c=u-k;
        return (c);
    }
    else 
    {
        if (((u-k)/26)==2)
        {
            int c=((u-k)%26)+78;
            return (c);
        }
        else
        {  
            int c=((u-k)%26)+52;
            return (c);
        }
    }
}

int dlowercalc(int u, int k)             //Algorithms to decypher lower case letters
{
    if(u-k>=97)
    {
        int c=u-k;
        return (c);
    }
    else
    {
        if (((u-k)/26)==3)
        {
            int c=((u-k)%26)+104;
            return (c);
        }
        else 
        {
            int c=((u-k)%26)+78;
            return (c);
        }
     }
}
```

The Program begins by asking the user whether he wants to Cypher or Decypher by inserting either char "c" or "d" and runs either the cyphmain (if cyphering) or dcecyphmain (if decphering) functions. This works fine

The program then asks the user for the rot number and then asks the user to input a phrase.  This also works fine.

However, after entering the words to (de)cypher the program crashes with a segmentation fault, which leads me to believe that the error lies in the maincalc/dmaincalc functions.  (Note that there are essentially two copies of each function one for cyphering and another for decyphering, they are exactly the same except for a few changes in the text  and the actual math involved in cyphering or decyphering the text).

Here's an example of the fault

```
Do You Want Cypher(c) or Decypher(d)?:d
What is the Cypher Number:2
Please enter the phrase that you would like to decode: Hello
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Use Valgrind to find the line number where it crashes.

Comment: You did not allocate space for the string either on the stack or on the heap.

Comment: And the argument for `scanf` should be a `char*` with the `%s` conversion, so `scanf("%s", s)` instead of `scanf("%s", &s)` (after allocating).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
char *s;
printf("Please enter the phrase that you would like to code:");  
scanf("%s",&s);
```

This does not allocate space for a string. You can either use `malloc` to allocate space, or put the string on the stack.

```
char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50); /* option 1*/
char s[50]; /* option 2 */
```

For option 1, note that `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, I just put that there for completeness. Also don't forget that you have to call `free(s)` when you're done with the string.

Comment: Ok, this works, but the issue now is that the string will only record one word.  A phrase such as "Hello World" only codes Hello but not world.  What do I need to do in order to get the string to read all the words and not just the first one?